# network drive auto disconnect after 10 mins in windows server 2003

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003, mappeddrive

I am working on windows server 2003 and when i run my script , it access data from remote
   network drive x: . so windows cannot make connection after 10 minutes , when i log off 
   my computer.
    so how to map my drive , and auto disconnect should get off.
    i have tried many solutions like net config server /autodisconnect:-1
    net use \mydrivename\mas90\home  but still it is not able to map my drive

```
only when i right click on shortcut of mas90 on desktop, network drive get mapped.
so how should i map my drive by using batch file
```

Comment: You can map a network drive though a batch file ran as a login script `NET USE X: \\server\path\to\folder` where X is the drive you want to it mapped to.

Answer (score 1):

My problem is solved by right click on my computer and using option map my drive

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is  Net use z: \servername\sharename [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]

The Z: is simply my example and you can use any unused drive letter.  The /PERSISTENT:Y would make this connection remain after a reboot.

Comment: thanks it solved my problem by directly mapping my drive by right  click on my computer , and it mapped even after logout